# Invert a series with coefficients depending on x

Tags: series-expansion, inverse

Let's say I have the equation:

$\qquad (8x^{15}+4x^{14}+\ldots)G^9 + (3x^{3}+\ldots)G^{8} + \ldots + (5x+4)G + x = x$.

$G$ is an infinite series of $x$. I want to find the first 10 coefficients of $G$. How exactly should I use `InverseSeries` to do this?

I've tried:

```
InverseSeries[
  Series[
    8x^{15} + 4x^{14} + \ldots)G^9 + (3x^{3} + \ldots) G^{8} + \ldots + (5x+4)G + x, 
    {G, 0, 10}], 
  {x, 0, 10}]
```

For inversion of series with coefficients—given numbers, it works, but it doesn't work here.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a simple example.

Comment: We really need to see a Mathematica expression that actually evaluates, not an expression with mixed TeX and Mathematica syntax and missing terms.

Comment: @sdd, try simple `InverseSeries[Series[8x^15 + 4x^14 + ...) G^9 + (3x^3 + ...) G^8 + ...,{G,0,10}]]`, then `CoefficientList[%,G]`.

Comment: You need to provide an example that other people can evaluate. Speaking of which, by "$G$  is an infinite series of $x$", did you mean $G$ is actually $G(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) for this purpose. Here is a random example:

```
eqn = (1 + x + x^2) g^3 + (2 + x - x^2) g^2 + g == 0;
```

Let's find the zeroth order approximation:

```
sol = Solve[eqn /. x->0, g]
```

> {{g -> -1}, {g -> -1}, {g -> 0}}

Let's find the series expansion around `-1` using [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve):

```
AsymptoticSolve[eqn, {g, -1}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> {{g -> -1 + 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[7]) x + ((3 I + Sqrt[7]) x^2)/Sqrt[
>       7] - ((-11 I + 21 Sqrt[7]) x^3)/(14 Sqrt[7])}, {g -> -1 + 
>       1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[7]) x + ((-3 I + Sqrt[7]) x^2)/Sqrt[
>       7] - ((11 I + 21 Sqrt[7]) x^3)/(14 Sqrt[7])}}

You can also not bother specifying the zeroth order approximation to `g`:

```
AsymptoticSolve[eqn, g, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> {{g -> 0}, {g -> -1 + 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[7]) x + ((3 I + Sqrt[7]) x^2)/Sqrt[
>       7] - ((-11 I + 21 Sqrt[7]) x^3)/(14 Sqrt[7])}, {g -> -1 + 
>       1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[7]) x + ((-3 I + Sqrt[7]) x^2)/Sqrt[
>       7] - ((11 I + 21 Sqrt[7]) x^3)/(14 Sqrt[7])}}

If you are working with an earlier version of Mathematica, but have access to the cloud, then you can define:

```
asymptoticSolve[a__] := CloudEvaluate[System`AsymptoticSolve[a]]
```

and then use `asymptoticSolve` instead of [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve).

Comment: I need the exact coefficients, so I simply need to find the inverse of the LHS series. Though, the coefficients are not given numbers, but just some polynomials in x. This should just change the system of equations a bit, that is solved when finding the inverse.
So, I am guessing there is a simple way using 
InverseSeries

Comment: @sdd My answer returns a series expression for `g` in terms of `x`. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: ok, you are right, but if we want to be precise, this series is not just asymptotic solution, not an exact one.

Comment: @sdd Just because the name of the function has Asymptotic in it doesn't mean the output is an asymptotic expansion. For this particular example, the output is just an ordernary series expansion.